# Is Kotlin 100% compatible with ART on Android?

Tags: android, bytecode, dalvik, kotlin

ART is the “new” Dalvik runtime on Android and have replaced it since Android 5.0. I’m really keen about Kotlin & JavaFX running on JVM v8. I’m not sure wich bytecode version the Kotlin compiler generates or is going to generate once it reaches v1.0 release state.

So the question is: Is ART capable of running “Kotlin code” now and will it be able to run Kotlin code in the future, e.g. when the Kotlin compiler is going to emit Java8 bytecode? Or does ART not depend on the bytecode emitted by the Kotlin compiler?

Comment: A small clarification: ART is not running Java bytecode but DEX code. The important factor is the Java bytecode to DEX compilation step (soon to be replaced by Java source to DEX by Jack & Jill). That's where the version of the Java bytecode comes into play.

Comment: @cypressious That means that the only way to write Android apps in another language than Java v<=7 would be a) build native Android binaries (e.g. using C++/Go) b) compile to Java bytecode and afterwards to native binaries (RoboVM’s approach) and c) compile straight to Google’s DEX code (Java v<=7)

Comment: I guess so. Apart from native stuff, as long as you have Java v<=7 bytecode, you're ok. Even with Jack & Jill, Jill will take care of that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Compatibility with Android is among our top priorities, so be sure that Kotlin will support ART when it's released. Currently Kotlin produces byte code version 1.6, so it's compatible, and we will continue  to support this target until majority of Android clients runs newer byte code versions.

Comment: Nice to hear that Android is a priority for Kotlin development. Personally I see Kotlin as the “Swift” for Android devs. RoboVM.org offers a bytecode compiler for iOS, so you can run “Kotlin code” on iOS as well which is even more important for me...